# Why Google Cloud KMS generating different encrypted ciphertext for same input text?

Tags: python, encryption, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-kms

I am trying to encrypt confidential and sensitive data using the Google Cloud Key Management Service (KMS) python API. I noticed in every iteration after the encryption that the same key for the exact input text generates different encrypted ciphertext. I mean, for the same input text, I am getting different encrypted ciphertext.

**My question is,**

1. why the encrypted ciphertext got changed? How to get the same encrypted ciphertext/value for the same input?
2. How the control the length of encrypted ciphertext?

**Here is the python code I used**

```
from google.cloud import kms
client = kms.KeyManagementServiceClient()
name = 'projects/sandbox/locations/global/keyRings/encryptdecrypt-keyring/cryptoKeys/encryptdecrypt-key_v01/cryptoKeyVersions/1' #CryptoKey info 
plaintext = b'hello123' # The data to encrypt

enc1=client.encrypt(request={'name': name, 'plaintext': plaintext})
```

Ref:

- [jupyter notebook screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yumaL.jpg)
- https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/encrypt-decrypt
- https://googleapis.dev/python/cloudkms/1.4.0/gapic/v1/api.html

Comment: `IV`, or Initialization Vector prevents the same plaintext from generating the same cyphertext. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector

Comment: It is a security feature that even with same key and plaintext the ciphertext differs (it's called **non determistic** encryption).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the system generates different ciphertext when encrypting the same input. This is an important security control for most encryption systems; it prevents the attack of an attacker getting you to encrypt a particular message M so they can determine if a ciphertext they have in hand, C, is also an encrypted copy of the same message M.

There are systems which offer consistent encryption outputs; the property is known as [Deterministic Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_encryption). However, I would suggest consulting with a cryptography expert before selecting a mechanism; these tools are tricky.

We make no commitment as to the exact length of the encrypted ciphertext; if you have a need for that to be predictable, I'd like to know more about why and how we can help.

Thanks for using GCP and Cloud KMS!